# Optional [] square brackets for a C Macro

Tags: c, preprocessor

Is it possible to have a optional `[/d]` parameter for a macro?

My current macro does something similar to this

```
DO_SOMETHING(Student,marks) add_marks(Student,marks)
```

Now sometimes the Student is an array or a single variable, so to use the macro on the student elements is it possible that my macro handles this ?

```
DO_SOMETHING(Student[10],80) as well as DO_SOMETHING(student,80)
```

Comment: macros just replace matching code with what you tell it to, so in your example you'd end up with `add_marks(Student[10],80)` and `add_marks(student,80)` - whether that will then compile or not depends on what `add_marks` is.

Comment: Don't use a macro, use a function taking an array as parameter. If you only need to change a single item, pass size 1 to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution is to modify function add_marks to have pointer like input parameters and the problem is gone.

```
add_marks(type *ptr, int size)
#define DO_SOMETHING(Student,marks)
/* in case of array DO_SOMETHING(Student,marks)
in case of variable DO_SOMETHING(&Student,marks) */
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you demonstrate what you mean with example code.